# WPF UserControls interfere with each other

Tags: wpf, datagrid, user-controls

Simply put: I have a UserControl that contains a DataGrid and some dependencyproperties to apply binding to the DataGrid.
Let's say I have 2 of these controls on a page. When I select a row in one control, this row is also selected in the other control! This is NOT something that I wish to happen.
Is this a typical WPF/.NET problem, or is it likely to be my mistake?

Comment: Well you didn't supply any useable code, i can only give you one hint, that might be a problem. If you have a custom dependency property which is a collection or reference type you must not give its default value directly in the dependency property definition via **new FrameworkPropertyMetaData( new List() ...*** . That way Every instance has the same value. If you want to correctly initialize these properties, you should do it in the normal constructor. Its a common mistake, so i thought you might have the same problem. If that doesn't help, you should post more informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question: No, it is not WPF problem, it is definitely your fault. You most likely have problem in the bindings or in the dependency property declarations.

If you want more detailed answer, you will have post more information, such as key parts of code behind and XAML.